# css print on A4 Page

Tags: css

On print am getting textarea topborder and scroll i just wanna disable top border and scroll from printed page

Comment: You should post your relevant HTML and CSS. This will help us to help you :)

Comment: Which browsers are you testing in? Browsers have even more differences compared to each other when it comes to print CSS. Is the top border and scroll visible in more than one browser?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that's easy. In your stylesheet, just add this nifty little bit:

```
textarea{
    border:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

Edit by Robert Pitt.

Would it not make more sense to specifically define the css within the print context:

```
@media print
{
    textarea
    {
        border:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've extended your answer, please remove if you wish.

Comment: No, that's a very good addition. However, I'm unsure if the OP wants to remove just the top border of the text boxes, or the borders altogether. In my mind just removing the top borders would make kind of a U shape, which would look very strange on the printed page. If he means margins, then I'd recommend he read up on the CSS box model.