# rails 3 print page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have generated graphs in my rails project, and i would like to add 'print page' option so that i can have the hardcopy of the graph. My page contains tabs,header,footer, but i would link to print only the graph protion.

So, please advise me how to go about it.

i have used following code to print page,

```
<%=link_to_function("Print this Page", "javascript:print()")%>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [CSS print stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) ([on StackOveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689017/css-print-on-a4-page)).